# Why low resolution device delete my left margins?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bla"
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:id="@+id/root_layout"
   android:layout_width="300dp" 
   android:layout_height="456dp"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:background="@drawable/signup_popup"
   android:padding="0dp">

      ...


                <LinearLayout 
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
               android:orientation="vertical"
            >
               <com.bla.view.text.blaTextView
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="52dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                  android:layout_weight="4"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:background="@drawable/signup_bt_blue"
                  android:padding="0dp"
                  android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
                  android:textSize="18dp"
                  android:textStyle="italic"
                  android:text="Sign in"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:clickable="true"
                  android:id="@+id/account_details_continue"
                  android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true"
               />

               <com.bla.view.text.blaTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            style="@style/textSignUp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="#8fc0ce"
            android:text="Already a blar?" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/account_details_title3"
         />
            </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

On high resolution devices (Nexus 4, 5) it shows the layout OK (see right figure in the attached image)

However when I deploy on low resolution devices (Nexus S, Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc S - LT18a.) it looks like the left figure in the attached image.

meaning `+id/account_details_continue"` is aligned to its parent left.

I'm using only one layout.xml not for each screen resolution

I have tried to put much wider margin to the right, but yet it looks the same

```
      <com.bla.view.text.blaTextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="52dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
          android:layout_weight="4"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:background="@drawable/signup_bt_blue"
          android:padding="0dp"
          android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
          android:textSize="18dp"
          android:textStyle="italic"
          android:text="Sign in"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:id="@+id/account_details_continue"
          android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true"
       />
```

How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: the problem could be that there isn't enough space to show everything. Are you using different layouts for different screens or just one generic ?

Comment: Android version of low-res devices ?

Comment: Please put the full xml file, you have "align_parentBottom" param so maybe the parent has some fault

Comment: @JafarKhQ Nexus S, Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc S - LT18a.

Comment: @mremremre1 look at my update- it didn't help either

Comment: so making a custom xml for small screens doesnt fix it ? Try using relative layout

Comment: mmm why you set your root view with fix size?? the root view MUST have match_parent on both dimension to fill the screen to the available size. If your screen (on low devices) is smaller than this size this could be the problem.

Comment: @Sulfkain i wanted the window to no span on all screen

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems to be a bug on Android 2.3.3

Changing child's margins to Parent padding solved this

```
        <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
       android:paddingLeft="12dp"
       android:paddingRight="12dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:orientation="vertical"
    >
       <com.bla.view.text.blaTextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="52dp"
          android:layout_weight="4"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:background="@drawable/signup_bt_blue"
          android:padding="0dp"
          android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
          android:textSize="18dp"
          android:textStyle="italic"
          android:text="Sign in"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:clickable="true"
          android:id="@+id/account_details_continue"
          android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true"
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to align your view:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Use it in relative layout. Notice that the width is wrap_content

Comment: i'll try. can you please explain what do you think may cause this?

Comment: @EladBenda I'm not sure but I think the problem is a combination of linear layout and small screens. I dont really use linear so I never seen it.

Comment: That's wierd. Anyway to stay in linearlayout?

Comment: @EladBenda no try my solution in relative